# Scikit-learn Expanded custom one-hot encoded matrix - not constructed from dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to construct a one-hot encoded matrix that represents additional categories that are not found in my sample.

If using the following code:

```
s = np.array(['man', 'man', 'woman', 'woman', 'son', 'son', 'son', 'son', 'son'])
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(s)
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
Y = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
print(Y)
```

The result is this:

```
[[1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

But in reality I have the following categories that some of which are not present in my dataset, yet I need to account for them:

```
categories = np.array(['man', 'woman', 'son', 'daughter', 'boy', 'girl', 'king', 'queen', 'baby', 'child'])
```

Thus what I need is this:

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Thus I am trying to figure out how to implement OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories=categories) in this code:

```
categories = np.array(['man', 'woman', 'son', 'daughter', 'boy', 'girl', 'king', 'queen', 'baby', 'child'])
s = np.array(['man', 'man', 'woman', 'woman', 'son', 'son', 'son', 'son', 'son'])
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
integer_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(s)
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories=categories)
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)
Y = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(integer_encoded)
print(Y)
```

But it gives the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

And if I change:

```
integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1)

to

integer_encoded = integer_encoded.reshape(len(integer_encoded), 1).all()
```

I get the following error:

```
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Can someone help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the `categories` parameter for `OneHotEncoder`
Your `categories` variable is `ndarray` and it is raising the `ValueError`.
Try using a regular *sorted* `list`.
AND ALSO, you don't need to use `LabelEncoder` in your case.

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

categories = [sorted(['man', 'woman', 'son',
                      'daughter', 'boy', 'girl',
                      'king', 'queen', 'baby', 'child'])]
print(f'sorted categories: {categories}')

s = np.array(['man', 'man', 'woman', 'woman',
              'son', 'son', 'son', 'son', 'son']).reshape(-1, 1)
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, categories=categories)
Y = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(s)
print(Y)
```

```
sorted categories: [['baby', 'boy', 'child', 'daughter', 'girl', 'king', 'man', 'queen', 'son', 'woman']]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```